# distilbert model is not working at ktrain

Tags: distilbert, ktrain

I tried to use distilbert classifier. but I am getting the following error.

This is my code

```
(X_train,y_train),(X_test,y_test),prepro 
=text.texts_from_df(train_df=data_train,text_column="Cleaned",label_columns=col

,val_df=data_test,maxlen=500,preprocess_mode="distilbert")
```

and here is the error

```
OSError: Model name 'distilbert-base-uncased' was not found in tokenizers model name list (distilbert-base-uncased, distilbert-base-uncased-distilled-squad, distilbert-base-cased, distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad, distilbert-base-german-cased, distilbert-base-multilingual-cased). We assumed 'distilbert-base-uncased' was a path, a model identifier, or url to a directory containing vocabulary files named ['vocab.txt'] but couldn't find such vocabulary files at this path or url._
```

Due to my office current environmental issue, I can only work on tf 2.2 and python 3.8. Right now I am using 0.19.

Do you think it will affect my current environment if I downgrade it to 0.16?

Answer (score 0):

This error may happen if there is a network or firewall issue preventing download of the tokenizer files.  See [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-do-i-use-ktrain-without-an-internet-connection) for remedies.

Also, when you use `preprocess_mode='distilbert'`, `texts_from*` functions return `TransformerDataset` instances, not arrays.  You'll need to replace `(X_train, y_train)` with `train_data`, for example. See [this example notebook](https://github.com/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/examples/text/20newsgroup-distilbert.ipynb).